# Login-AzureRmAccount not working

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

New to Azure. I am following [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/) to setup key vault.

I have an MSDN subscription setup by my company.

But when i try to run `Login-AzureRmAccount` and give in the MSDN credential I cannot login.

I can login though with the same credentials to Azure Portal.

Error is invalid credentials.  I am using a windows 7 PC, is that ok?

Comment: Did you try Add-AzureAccount?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Do try, Add-AzureAccount (though that won't fix, just give you more info) and then tweet @AzureSupport (or file a support req via the portal) - something sounds off on that account

Comment: There is no issue with using windows 7. What version of powershell and Azure Cmdlets are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with you Subscription Name in it:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionName [The name of your subscription]
```

Comment: I have an MSDN subscription, so I have a username(company email) and password.  what would be the subscription name?

Comment: You can see that under subscription when you log into the portal.